# How to remove the first X directories in path?

Tags: command-line

I have a command that runs like follows:

```
./command shortened_path_to_current_directory
```

The output of `pwd` is

```
/path/to/current/directory
```

and `shortened_path_to_current_directory` is:

```
/current/directory
```

so it removes the first 2 directories in the path.

Is a way to run the command with something like

```
./command shorten($PWD)
```

where `shorten` is something that removes the `/path/to`?

Answer (score 0):

Using *parameter expansion*:

```
$ echo "/${PWD#*[a-z]*/[a-z]*/}"
/current/directory
```

See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash.
Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe